# lua generic for-loop specification

Tags: generics, for-loop, lua

I am working with Lua 5.0, what puzzles me is why the following code works:

```
for i in {first=1,second=2,third=3} do
    print(i)
end
```

It prints 'first', 'second', 'third'. However, according to the online programming in Lua for 5.0
"The first thing the for does is to evaluate the expressions after the in. These expressions should result in the three values kept by the for: the iterator function, the invariant state, and the initial value for the control variable."

In this case, the expression after the in is simply a table. It won't evaluate into (function, state, initial value), and any subsequent call would be a call to the table itself. But the above example works, why?

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned for-loop is valid for version 4.0, see http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#4.4

A for statement like

```
   for index, value in exp do block end
```

is equivalent to the code:

```
   do
     local _t = exp
     local index, value = next(t, nil)
     while index do
       block
       index, value = next(t, index)
     end
   end
```

As shown, the "exp" after "in" could be a table. This is drastically different from the for syntax in 5.0 and onwards. However, my experiment shows that the 5.0 still respects this old style. This explains what I saw.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua 5.2 (the standard) this code produces the error

```
Runtime Error:
tst.lua:1: attempt to call a table value
```

So I don't know what you're doing, but either way, what you are doing is *wrong*.

Comment: As said, i am using Lua 5.0, here is the output:

> for i in {first=1,second=2} do print(i) end

first

second

>